# rsync creating thousands of .DS_Store files from mounted volume

Tags: macos, network-shares, rsync

I've been using *rsync* on OS X to sync all our website admins.  It was working fine until the OS X 10.6.3 update!

Now it creates thousands of empty (0-kb) folders. It only does it when synching to a mounted network drive (which we need to do) as when I sync to my local drive it works as usual!

I've tried excludes which don't seem to be working... also tried a different version of rsync so it's an OS X issue.

```
echo ""
echo "~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*"
echo " SYNCING up KINEMASTIK"
echo "~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*"

/usr/local/bin/rsync -aNHAXv --progress --exclude-from 'exclude.txt' /Volumes/Groups/Projects/483_Modern_Activity_Website/web/youradmin/ /Users/dan/Dropbox/documents/WORK/kinemastik/WEBSITE/youradmin/  

echo ""
echo "~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*"
echo " SYNCING up CHRIS BROOKS YOURADMIN"
echo "~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*"

/usr/local/bin/rsync -aNHAXv --progress --exclude-from 'exclude.txt' /Volumes/Groups/Projects/483_Modern_Activity_Website/web/youradmin/ /Volumes/Groups/Projects/516_ChrisBrooks/website/youradmin/
```

Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Comment: What are the `N`, `A` and `X` flags for ? I don't see these listed in `man rsync` on Mac OS X 10.6.3. Try just `rsync -nHv`...

Comment: I'm having the same problem, using flags -arpV. The rsync was working the first time I ran it, but I hit a an error on a file. I deleted that file and restarted it and ever since then, it doesn't seem to do anything except for create those .DS_STORE files.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I recently had the issue, found the answer elsewhere (http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=116751), and wanted to share it.

Apparently it happens b/c rsync attempts to create a temp file to which it copies the file before it renames it.  The temp file name is in the form of ".{filename}.{some unique id}".  Since the file is ".DS_Store" it creates "..DS_Store.{some unique id}".  But it seems OS X has trouble w/ files that start w/ ".." so rsync fails quietly and tries again (repeat ad nauseum).

The solution is to ignore the .DS_Store file.

People have also had trouble deleting these ..DS_Store.{some unique id} files.  To delete them run:

```
find . -name '..DS_Store*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

**ERRATA:**

The command above to delete the files didn't end up working for me.  I had to move to my Windows machine (which is connected to this external drive via an Airport Extreme) and delete the files.  I imagine mounting the drive directly to my Mac via firewire may have also worked.

Comment: By ignoring you mean what @JRobert suggested? Or how do you ignore?

Comment: Yes, what JRobert suggested.  And for the record, the cmd to delete the ..DS_Store files ended up not working for me.  I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: wrt `find . -name '..DS_Store*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm`: this actually **does** seem to work on my macOS Ventura using GNU's `find-utils` pkg via MacPorts. But I run it like this: `find /Volumes/MyBackups -name '.DS_Store' | xargs rm`

Answer (score 1):

Broken rsync command syntax?  A quick check of the man file on my machine (10.6.3) shows:

```
   --exclude-from=FILE     read exclude patterns from FILE
```

Comment: No. The `=` is _optional_ here, as it is on all `--options` in `rsync`.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me too. I havent tried it yet but a temporary fix is to exclude all invisible files, at least according to a post on the subject in Apple's Discussions.

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2398971&tstart=60

Answer (score 0):

As I recall you can stop that behaviour easily with [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/pgs/english/apps.html): there should be (in one of the last tabs) the possibility to disable the creation of DS_STORE files to remote computers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `rsync` option used (`--exclude-from 'exclude.txt'`) is correct syntax. It will work provided:

1. your script knows **where** `exclude.txt` is located
2. the content of `exclude.txt` includes the following line: `.DS_Store`
3. your `--exclude-from` option is declared "early" in the `rsync` invocation; IOW:

```
# THIS: 
/usr/local/bin/rsync --exclude-from 'exclude.txt' -aNHAXv --progress /Volumes/Groups/Projects/483_Modern_Activity_Website/web/youradmin/ /Users/dan/Dropbox/documents/WORK/kinemastik/WEBSITE/youradmin/
# NOT THIS:
/usr/local/bin/rsync -aNHAXv --progress --exclude-from 'exclude.txt' ...
```

[`.DS_Store`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) files are an Apple plague, and recent observations suggest the plague is getting worse.